# What questions should I be able to answer when I want to enter the USA on the 4th time?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, airport-security

On my 3rd visit to the US this June, I went to a second screening and the immigration officer asked a lot of questions.

My 1st trip was last January for only 1 week: my 2nd trip in March was for 2 weeks, and my most recent and 3rd trip was in June for  13 days. They had the same entry point, Las Vegas.

I'm worried because I will be coming back for Thanskgiving and I forgot the answers that I told him. I said some nonsense stuff like I want to blog but I haven't started it yet and he asked me deeper nonsense things and he was typing on the computer while asking me. Do you think after 5 months when I visit again the United states, particularly Las Vegas, the officer will ask me about the questions from last time?

im getting paranoid about the blogging thing because i realized now that its like  working but truthfully i havent started it yet or have a video of my self in the us. only pictures. will it be a problem on my next entry? i mean when they ask me questions again? and if for thanksgiving sounds like is for family, what can i tell them? im really visiting my friend's home for thanksgiving

Comment: The location probably does not matter. The notes from your prior interviews will be in a database that will be available to your interviewer at any port of entry. Can you clarify the sort of questions they asked? Were your answers accurate?

Comment: This is the reason you should always tell the truth.

Comment: I would sit down and spend some time trying to recall what you might have said, especially anything that could have indicated an intention to work (‘I want to blog’, for example). Then get your story straight for your next visit - the truth about your ties to home, reason for your visit this time etc.

Comment: What were your reasons for visiting the US? Going "for Thanksgiving" sounds like you were visiting family.

Comment: they asked me: 1. who bought your ticket? i answered my friend bought it for me because we had a transaction before and he used his card instead to pay me. ( i got so comfortable answering his casual questions at first like, when did you start blogging? and i said, Im planning to start my own channel but not yet. i have a lot of followers but its on facebook, i said. he also asked me, you will stay here for  2 weeks, what are you going to do here? so i said, i will shop, go to LA, universal studios again and i thought he wasnt convinced but im really just there for tour.

Comment: im getting paranoid about the blogging thing because i realized now that its like a working but truthfully i havent started it yet or have a video of my self in the us. only pictures. will it be a problem on my next entry? i mean when they ask me questions again? and if for thanksgiving sounds like is for family, what can i tell them? im really visiting my friend's home for thanksgiving

Comment: This is also why you should keep all answers short and sweet. Why are you traveling? "Vacation" is all you need to say, if that's the truth.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove information in a way that makes the existing answers impossible to understand.

Answer (score 17):

**You have made life very hard for yourself by lying.**

As @Willeke says this is one of the reasons we always advise people to tell the truth (apart from the very bad consequences of being caught in a lie).

it is likely that the officer in your next visit has a record of your answers from the previous visits, and somewhat likely that he will ask you one or two questions based on them. So you should do two things:

1. Do your best to recall what you said last time and be consistent.
2. From now on always tell the truth to border officials.

The second is the most important.

Comment: I'd add 1.a. To the extent possible, make what you said you were going to be doing happen, or have thought out the reasons why you didn't do what you said you had intended to do (people do change their plans over time, so such does happen).